# why cant i return multiple values here?

Tags: java

> Basically the code shows the difference between Alicepoints and BobPoints.But when i am returning them it just doesnt run.

But when i run the code this error is shown.

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
at Solution.solve(Solution.java:12)
at Solution.main(Solution.java:33)"
```

which  is unexpected.the code is shown below

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.text.*;
    import java.math.*;
    import java.util.regex.*;
    import java.math.*;
    import java.util.regex.*;

    public class Solution {

    static int[] solve(){
    // Complete this function
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a0 = in.nextInt();
    int a1 = in.nextInt();
    int a2 = in.nextInt();
    int b0 = in.nextInt();
    int b1 = in.nextInt();
    int b2 = in.nextInt();
    int pointsAlice,pointsBob;
    pointsAlice = ((a0>b0)?1:0)+ ((a1>b1)?1:0)+ ((a2>b2)?1:0) ;
    pointsBob = ((a0<b0)?1:0)+ ((a1<b1)?1:0)+ ((a2<b2)?1:0) ;
    int ar[] = new int[2];
    ar[0]=pointsAlice;
    ar[1]=pointsBob;
    return ar;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Solution m=new Solution();
    int rr[] = new int[2];
      rr = m.solve();


    System.out.println(rr[0] +" " + rr[1]);  




    }
}
```

Comment: The error message explains the problem very well...

Comment: it works fine with me!

Comment: Same for me as for @YCF_L

Comment: What are you using as input??

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine, Nevertheless couple of points.

- You don't really need to create an object of `Solution` to call the `solve()` method. you can do it as shown below, since it is `static`.
- You don't need to create a new `int[]` to store the result returned by `solve();`

  `int rr[] = Solution.solve(); //note that I didn't create a new array.`

Comment: thanks anyway i solved it using the hint provided by Tahseem in above comment which is similar to yours

Answer (score 0):

The problem is nothing to do with *returning* values.  The problem is that the input you are trying to read is not in the form that the program can handle.

The code as written will work if you run it with input that starts with 6 integers with white-space between them.  If you give it something else, one of those `nextInt` calls will throw `InputMismatchException` (if a token isn't an integer) or `NoSuchElementException` (if you get to the end of the stream).  Then it will crash because you are not handling these exceptions.